# How to make covariant in scala a java generic method with a parameterized return type

Tags: scala, generics, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to write in Scala a credentials repository implementing the Google API Java client interfaces:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory

class CredentialRepository extends DataStore[StoredCredential] {
  ... // Implementation
}

class CredentialDataStoreFactory extends DataStoreFactory {

  val store = new CredentialRepository

  def getDataStore[V <: Serializable](id: String): DataStore[V] = store

}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
type mismatch; found : CredentialRepository required: com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore[V]
```

How can I make getDataStore covariant so I can return a CredentialRepository?

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle. The problem is that the interface you have to implement doesn't make sense. You simply cannot promise that `getDataStore` will return a `DataStore[V]` for any `V` in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
def getDataStore(id: String): DataStore[StoredCredential] = store
```

This should work.

I feel that having a generic `V` there doesn't make sense to me since the returned type is defined and not generic.

EDIT:

If the java interface needs such a type parameter, you could constrain it:

```
def getDataStore[V <: StoredCredential with Serializable](id: String): DataStore[V] = store
```

Or

```
def getDataStore[V <: StoredCredential with Serializable](id: String): DataStore[StoredCredential] = store
```

Comment: This contradicts contract of `DataStoreFactory` interface.
`public interface DataStoreFactory {
  <V extends Serializable> DataStore<V> getDataStore(String id) throws IOException;
}`

Comment: With the first and the third solution I get: `overriding method getDataStore in trait DataStoreFactory of type [V <: java.io.Serializable](x$1: String)com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore[V]; method getDataStore has incompatible type`

Comment: With the second: `type mismatch; found : CredentialRepository required: com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore[V] Note: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential >: V (and CredentialRepository <: com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore[com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential]), but Java-defined trait DataStore is invariant in type V. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as _ >: V. (SLS 3.2.10)`

Comment: A true Java horror story :D